# Run Cron job every 10 minutes between two hours

Tags: cron, cpanel, schedule

I want to run a script at every 10 minutes between 10-14 hours, i tried this solution but it doesn't work:

```
*/10 10-14 * * * /usr/local/bin/ea-php71 /home2/jaki/public_html/fix/index.php
```

[image: cpanel settings cronjob]

I tried once per minute or once per five minutes and works great.

Any solution?

Comment: That format [_should_](https://crontab.guru/#*/10_10-14_*_*_*) give the right outcome; what do you observe?

Comment: @Ja͢ck, nothing, the script doesn't run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

The server are using UTC-04:00, so i need to adjust my hours according to those of the server